# mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: mongodb, shared-libraries

Does anybody know what this error means?
"mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I have uninstalled mongo using

> sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev
>
> sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen
>
> sudo apt-get autoremove

and restarted my machine (Ubuntu 16.04).
Oddly, when I enter

> mongo

on the command-line, I get the same error, despite mongo having been uninstalled.

> mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

edit: there was a mongo file in usr/local/bin. Deleted, and now

> mongo

on commandline returns the expected

> command not found: mongo

Any thoughts on what's going wrong and how to fix it?

//I'm going to re-install mongo now...

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Mongodb fixed the issue.